# Gnome 3.4 partially or totally freeze

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gpu

I'm using an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Since, I discovered that there are other desktops on Ubuntu, rather than Unity, I installed Gnome 3.4.

But it freezes time by time, when I run many applications or little. Sometimes I can enter into no GUI with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and to restart my GDM, sometimes not, but my music is still playing in background, so I think kernel is not blocked, it's a GPU problem or maybe another. Please give me some advice or maybe you know what the problem is and the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience Gnome with Ubuntu is always unstable, unless if you are a pro. But if you are interested, you can use [Ubuntu Gnome](http://ubuntugnome.org/). It's the official Gnome flavor of Ubuntu and the site will be updated today for 13.04 Ubuntu release after few minutes.

Comment: This. Gnome Ubuntu is an official flavor now.